# Padding with <td> / <tr>

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have the following code:

HTML

```
<div id="box">
<tr><div class="wrapper"><div class="text">something</div></div><td><a href="#" ><img class="square" src="http://i.imm.io/1ld94.png"/></a><a href="#" ><img src="http://i.imm.io/1ld98" class="square" /></a></td></tr><hr>
<tr><div class="wrapper"><div class="text">something</div></div><td><a href="#" ><img class="square" src="http://i.imm.io/1ld94.png"/></a><a href="#" ><img src="http://i.imm.io/1ld98" class="square" /></a></td></tr><hr>
<tr><div class="wrapper"><div class="text">In this text, what I really want is for the div to word-wrap around somewhere in (ignore ....) THIS point instead of going on on top of the green square</div></div><td><a href="#" ><img class="square" src="http://i.imm.io/1ld94.png"/></a><a href="#" ><img src="http://i.imm.io/1ld98" class="square" /></a></td></tr><hr>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
    padding-right:100px;
    display:inline;
}

.text{
display:inline;
position:relative;
font-family:lucida grande,tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
letter-spacing: 0px; 
}

.square{
    width: 20px;
    float: right;
    vertical-align:text-top;
    display:block;
}

#box{
    height: 575px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    padding:20px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TQh3L/2/

In the left image the image (little box) is being wrapped by the text. I want the text to appear to the left, and the image to float next to it as if it was in the next column, and be valigned to middle.

[image]

//another thing, this was optimal to my own screen resolution, so basically what I really want is to wrap around the first "column" as so to not write on top of the green square. Thank you!

Comment: Please can you post the problem here, not in the fiddle?

Comment: the problem is here... but you really need to see the fiddle because it's hard to explain. "//another thing, this was optimal to my own screen resolution, so basically what I really want is to wrap around the first "column" as so to not write on top of the green square. Thank you!"

Comment: Are you asking "How do I vertically align to the middle an image within a block of text?"

Comment: Your table syntax doesn't conform to how a table should be constructed. Ignoring thead/tfoot/tbody, the table structure must be  `<table><tr><td>anything</td><td.../></tr><tr.../></table>` - you can't stick divs inbewteen a tr and a td. By `<td.../>` and `<tr.../>` I mean you can have multiples.

Comment: actually I can... it's not supposed to be a table but it should behave as one. It's identical to css "display: table-cell" or just table for example. It's fairly easy to understand seeing the fiddle, I just want to keep a "private" space for the green square as so it doesn't get overrun by the text

Comment: No you can't. Adding `display: table-cell` doesn't make a div a valid td. CSS affects the display, not the markup. It may appear to work for you but it's invalid HTML.

Comment: "Adding display: table-cell doesn't make a div a valid td." I never said it did but the display is as one (it's inherited), it simulates. Nevertheless I believe the problem has nothing to do with that.

Comment: No it's not but there are some things you could get right. I sincerely hope you consider why validation is important.

Comment: I certainly understand the reasoning of what you are saying and I thank you for forwarding my attention to that!

Comment: Actually, I've just noticed that it is the invalid markup that's the issue. With valid markup that td with text would not interfere with the td that has the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TQh3L/4/)**

Yes, so if I understand correctly, you just want the width of the text to not cross the vertical space of your link column.

Your `display inline` was not allowing me not to set a width for text, so I had to take it out.

Comment: yes, that's basically it! but unfortunately without inline the following happens... http://postimg.org/image/oq3mjwcjj/ instead of the square being on top of the <hr> it keeps "inline" with it instead of lined with the text... any idea on why and how to fix this? Thanks for that advance!

Comment: I included a `hr` css selector in my Fiddle to adjust for this. You can adjust the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` appropriately. I'm curious about how you got them to overlap though.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the full markup for a `table`?  `<table>` tags can only have children of `<tr>`, `<thead>`, `<tfoot>`, and `<tbody>`.  Additionally, `<tr>`/`<td>` should only be the children of table tags.  Using the tags any other way is playing with undefined behavior.

```
<div id="box">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="wrapper">
                <div class="text">something</div>
            </td>
            <td><a href="#"><img class="square" src="http://i.imm.io/1ld94.png"/></a><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imm.io/1ld98" class="square" /></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr/>
    <table>
        ...
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/UwtWE/)

Here is a demo adding content to the table dynamically (which could be AJAX):

[Dynamic Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H5LNF/)

Comment: I had planned on doing that at the beginning but then I took notice I would need to use AJAX in a beautiful - at ease - way of updating information to the user. To my knownledge, tables won't allow that smoothly and with insertion of content on the middle of the table with particular animations for example...

Comment: Well, then really you need to be asking a question about how to do your AJAX/animation.  Here you are asking people to fix problems arising from undefined behavior.  If you fix it in one browser, it may not work in another browser, even in a future version.  You should be able to use AJAX with a table just fine.  It might take a little more work, but no reason why it will break.  Also, you could use CSS and `div`/`span` elements to do what you need.

Comment: @user3050963 how many more developers need to tell you it's the table that's the issue? You need to work out how to do the ajax without destroying the valid table markup. Ask a question about that instead. And please consider how important standards are in web development!

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the markup so that the floating anchor tags are **before** the wrapper div.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/TQh3L/3/)**

```
<a href="#" ><img class="square" src="http://i.imm.io/1ld94.png"/></a>
<a href="#" ><img src="http://i.imm.io/1ld98" class="square" /></a>

<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="text">In this text, what I really want is for the div to word-wrap around somewhere in (ignore ....) THIS point instead of going on on top of the green square</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but the text is now below the green square :b I don't want it to even "touch" the boundaries.

Comment: I get the impression you want it valign centre, Danield thinks you want it at the top. Now you're adding touching the boundaries into the mix. Could you please describe the question with an image (drawn in paint will do)?